# Limit number of parameters per method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, parameters

Assuming the parameters are all the same type, is there a rule of thumb in regards to the number of parameters for a method?  Im just wondering where I should draw the line and what my alternatives are (ie interface, array, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it really depends on your case.  Are you doing something to the entire set?  Validating all the items or aggregating data, for example?  In that case, I would pass in an IEnumerable as a single parameter.

Passing in a lot of parameters can be a good sign of poor separation of concerns (i.e. your method is doing too much), but it sounds like in this case you're passing in a well defined set of items to iterate them in some way.  Given the collection initializer syntax in C# 3, I would recommend IEnumerable in pretty much every case over a list of parameters that would be something like `Type a, Type b, Type c...`.

Of course, if your parameters are actually treated differently, then separating them out makes sense, but I would consider what you're doing in that case.  A simple case that comes to mind would be building a tree data structure and having a function to build up the children of a node.  A poor syntax might be:

```
Node BuildTree( Node parent, Node child1, Node child2...)
```

I would probably pursue something more like:

```
void ConstructChildren( this Node parent, IEnumerable<Node> children)
```

If you can provide more information about your case, though, and what sort of logic you're performing on the parameters, it would probably be easier to see if it's a good candidate for collapsing or refactoring.

Comment: I wold like to take these parameters and export them to an XML file.  My knee-jerk reaction was to simply make them all a string but after looking at your example, I think it would be best to include the type.   That being said, each param will be different.  
    myCar(Seat bucket, Rims Spinners, Name Hoopdie)   Although it is possible there might be more than one param using the same type.

Comment: Using the native XML Serializer or something custom?  Either way, I would probably take either an IEnumerable<object> if you're using the native serializer or IEnumerable<BaseType>, assuming you have a base entity class where your custom serialization logic lives (common in my experience).

Answer (score 10):

Steve McConnell addresses this in [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/), citing research that suggests people can't really handle more than seven chunks of information at a time, making seven a common-sense limit wherever it's practical.

In the concluding paragraph of that section (page 178 in the second edition), he writes:

> If you find yourself consistently
>   passing more than a few arguments, the
>   coupling among your routines is too
>   tight ... If you are passing the same
>   data to many different routines, group
>   the routines into a class and treat
>   the frequently used data as class
>   data.

Answer (score 3):

I try to limit it to 4 or so. Some people say less, some say more.

The alternative to tons of parameters would be to create an operation class, i.e. replace:

```
func(boo, far, lint, pizza, flags);
```

with

```
var action = new DoSomethingObject(boo, far, lint);
action.Food = pizza;
action.Go(flags);
```

This has a few advantages over the function:

- If some parameters are optional, you can expose them as properties (such as `pizza` above).
- If your function takes that many arguments, chances are it does a lot, and could be broken into smaller functions. A class helps you do this cleanly.

Comment: What if your API has many methods that accept many arguments? does it seem appropriate to create a "data container" class per method? This class's single purpose is to be used when being passed to its matching method and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be passing an unknown number of arguments, you should use [varargs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or pass a IEnumerable.  Of course, sometimes you pass a fixed number of items of the same type.  In the latter case, the fixed number should follow from the method's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for greater call-site readability, you could use a params parameter list (the varargs mentioned before), so instead of

```
void ConstructChildren( Node parent, IEnumerable<Node> children)
....
List<Node> children = new List<Node> {child1, child2, child3};
ConstructChildren(parent, children);
```

I would use

```
void ConstructChildren( Node parent, params Node[] children)
...
ConstructChildren( parent, child1, child2, child3);
```

However, the params syntax gets ugly to look at if you use more that 5-6-7 items in the children collection.